# LaTeX3 pad something unexpandable

Tags: expl3, programming

I'm trying to implement the Gray code in LaTeX. The current setup works and outputs the following (the commas are for visual distinction):

[image: gray code]

(intended output:) 0,1; 00,01,11,10; 000, 001, 011, 010, 110, 111,101, 100

The gray code produces these sequence by applying xor to two binary numbers (which I get from `\int_to_bin:n` and which are only as long as they need to be, so not padded).

Unfortunately my `\__graycode_xor:nn` function is unexpandable, which in turn means I cannot measure its length to apply some padding at the end (to make every bit sequence equally long).

What I've tried: Saving the `\graycode_at:n` part into a tl variable with different levels of expansion, but it didn't work, because there were unexpanded parts that made the measurement of length impossible.

*Question:* How can I measure the length of something unexpandable to pad its content with zeros?

---

*Edit:* I already do some kind of padding for the bitwise operation, which seems to break expandability, but my main concern is the outcome (to pad the result which is placed in the input stream).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_to_bin:n { V }

% xor on two bits
% #1 and #2: either 0 or 1
\cs_new:Npn \__graycode_xor_bits:nn #1#2
    {
        \int_compare:nTF { #1 = #2 }
            { 0 } { 1 }
    }

% does bitwise xor on two token lists containing binary numbers
% #1 and #2: binary numbers
\cs_new:Npn \__graycode_xor:nn #1#2
    {
        % set the sequences (of bits) for bitwise operations
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { #2 }
        % compute the padding
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \fp_eval:n { abs(\tl_count:N \l_tmpa_tl - \tl_count:N \l_tmpb_tl) } }
        \int_compare:nT { \tl_count:N \l_tmpa_tl < \tl_count:N \l_tmpb_tl }
            {
                % pad \l_tmpa_tl
                \prg_replicate:nn { \l_tmpa_int }
                    { \tl_put_left:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { 0 } }
            }
        \int_compare:nT { \tl_count:N \l_tmpb_tl < \tl_count:N \l_tmpa_tl }
            {
                % pad \l_tmpb_tl
                \prg_replicate:nn { \l_tmpa_int }
                    { \tl_put_left:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { 0 } }
            }
        \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \tl_count:N \l_tmpa_tl }
            {
                \__graycode_xor_bits:nn { \tl_item:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 } } { \tl_item:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { ##1 } }
            }
    }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__graycode_xor:nn { xx }

% compute the graycode at a specific place
% #1: a decimal number
\cs_new:Npn \graycode_at:n #1
    {
        \__graycode_xor:xx
            { \int_to_bin:n { #1 - 1 } }
            { \int_to_bin:n { \fp_eval:n { floor((#1-1)/2) } } }
    }

% UI for gray code
% #1: 2^n with n in N
\NewDocumentCommand { \graycode } { m }
    {
        % compute the required number of places (for paddings)
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \fp_eval:n { floor(ln(#1)/ln(2)) } }
        % generate gray code till current place
        \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
            {
                % TODO: pad this
                \graycode_at:n { ##1 },
            }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \graycode{2}\quad
    \graycode{4}\quad
    \graycode{8}\par
    \graycode{16}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `% set the sequences (of bits) for bitwise operations` ensures that it is not expandable, you can probably do it without any such assignments, but why do you need it to be expandable?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because I do want to pad it with zeros, so that each bit sequence in a row has the same length. The easiest way seems to be to measure the length of a token list, but that doesn't work if it isn't expandable. But I'm open to ideas.

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but it's possible you may get ideas from looking at the [`binhex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/binhex) and [`xint`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xint) packages.

Comment: At first sight, what's the idea in `\graycode` with `% compute the required number of places (for paddings)`? You are setting `\l_tmpa_int` and then setting it again inside `\__graycode_xor:nn`? Why not declare your own integers (and other variables) rather than (ab)using “tmp” variables?

Comment: @Manuel Well, the tmp variables are for testing. You are right that in the UI function it should be an own variable. The idea behind that one is that it holds the number of places the `\graycode_at:n` output should be extended to.

Comment: I'm not sure that I get the problem. Don't you know from the argument `16` already that \graycode{16} needs four bits and so that the sequence should start with `0000`? Why do you need to measure it? Or do you mean another length?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I do know that, but I don't know how to get the binary representation to always have 4 digits (especially since the digits are xor'ed). That's why I said I have troubles with padding the output with zeros.

Comment: You mean your actually question is how to print a binary number in a fix length by adding zeros if necessary?

Comment: Remark: the standard way in TeX to pass some result (the xor) computed by something unexpandable (the xor macro) to something else (the pad function) is to have the unexpandable macro set some result (compare: `\pgfmathresult`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked how to measure something unexpandable. The answer actually lies in the question: you measure it.

You can locally select a font with fixed width numbers and set the unexpandable content into a hbox. By dividing the width of the hbox by the width of one number, you get the number of digits. If you accept printing the result in this font you could even use leaders for the padding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_to_bin:n { V }

% xor on two bits
% #1 and #2: either 0 or 1
\cs_new:Npn \__graycode_xor_bits:nn #1#2
    {
        \int_compare:nTF { #1 = #2 }
            { 0 } { 1 }
    }

% does bitwise xor on two token lists containing binary numbers
% #1 and #2: binary numbers
\cs_new:Npn \__graycode_xor:nn #1#2
    {
        % set the sequences (of bits) for bitwise operations
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { #2 }
        % compute the padding
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \fp_eval:n { abs(\tl_count:N \l_tmpa_tl - \tl_count:N \l_tmpb_tl) } }
        \int_compare:nT { \tl_count:N \l_tmpa_tl < \tl_count:N \l_tmpb_tl }
            {
                % pad \l_tmpa_tl
                \prg_replicate:nn { \l_tmpa_int }
                    { \tl_put_left:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { 0 } }
            }
        \int_compare:nT { \tl_count:N \l_tmpb_tl < \tl_count:N \l_tmpa_tl }
            {
                % pad \l_tmpb_tl
                \prg_replicate:nn { \l_tmpa_int }
                    { \tl_put_left:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { 0 } }
            }
        \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \tl_count:N \l_tmpa_tl }
            {
                \__graycode_xor_bits:nn { \tl_item:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 } } { \tl_item:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { ##1 } }
            }
    }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__graycode_xor:nn { xx }

% compute the graycode at a specific place
% #1: a decimal number
\cs_new:Npn \graycode_at:n #1
    {
        \__graycode_xor:xx
            { \int_to_bin:n { #1 - 1 } }
            { \int_to_bin:n { \fp_eval:n { floor((#1-1)/2) } } }
    }

% UI for gray code
% #1: 2^n with n in N
\NewDocumentCommand { \graycode } { m }
    {
      \leavevmode
        % TODO: Select font with fixed-width numbers
        % compute the required number of places (for paddings)
        \hbox_set:Nn\l_tmpa_box{\int_to_bin:n{#1-1}}
        % generate gray code till current place
        \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
            {
                \hbox_to_wd:nn{\box_wd:N\l_tmpa_box}{
                  \leaders\hbox:n{0}\hfil
                  \graycode_at:n { ##1 }
                },
            }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \graycode{2}\quad
    \graycode{4}\quad
    \graycode{8}\par
    \graycode{16}
\end{document}
```

But to solve your actual problem it might be easier to add the padding at the beginning and rewrite `\__graycode_xor:nn` to keep the padding intact. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% xor on two bits
% #1 and #2: either 0 or 1
\cs_new:Npn \__graycode_xor_bits:nn #1#2
    {
        \int_compare:nNnTF{#1}={#2}
            { 0 } { 1 }
    }
\cs_new:Npn\__graycode_xor:w#1#2\q_stop#3#4\q_stop{
  \__graycode_xor_bits:nn{#1}{#3}
  \tl_if_empty:nF{#2}{
    \__graycode_xor:w#2\q_stop#4\q_stop
  }
}
\cs_new:Nn\__graycode_xor:nn{
  \__graycode_xor:w#1\q_stop#2\q_stop
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn\__graycode_xor:nn{ff}
\cs_new:Nn\graycode_at:nn{
  \__graycode_xor:ff
    { \tl_tail:f{\int_to_bin:n { #1 - 1 + #2 } } }
    { \tl_tail:f{\int_to_bin:n { \fp_eval:n { floor((#1-1)/2) + #2 } } } }
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \graycode } { m }
    {
        % generate gray code till current place
        \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
            {
                \graycode_at:nn { ##1 }{ #1 },
            }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
    \graycode{2}\quad
    \graycode{4}\quad
    \graycode{8}\par
    \graycode{16}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**:
This implementation of `\__graycode_xor:nn` is based on recursion:
By passing the arguments to `\__graycode_xor:w` the first digits are split off.
Then it calculates the bitwise XOR for the first digits (`#1` and `#3`).
If `#2` the remaining part of the first argument is not empty, there are additional bits to XOR, so we recursively call the macro for the trailing part.
This assumes that the arguments have the same length, but this is always true for this algorithm because padding was added at the beginning.

Comment: +1 Great answer (it works as expected). Would it be possible to explain what your code does (it seems to do recursion based on whether the first argument to xor is atomic or not, does it)?