# How I draw this KV-Diagram in Latex?

Tags: karnaugh

Hello my Problem is I've no idea. How I draw this Kv-Diagram in Latex I only found different KV-Diagrams they make with the Karnaugh maps.
I only can do this table with Latex. I've no idea how to add the red lines/annotation.

[image: my KV Diagramm]

```
\documentclass{standalone}  
\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{c |c |c|c |c |c} 
 $y_0$ & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$x_0$} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{$\overline{x_0}$}\\ \cline{1-5}
 $x_1$    &1&0&0&1&$\overline{x_3}$\\\cline{2-6}
       &0&1&1&0&$x_3$\\\cline{1-5}
 $\overline{x_1}$   &0&1&1&0&\\\cline{2-6}
       &1&0&0&1&$\overline{x_3}$\\\cline{2-5}
       &$\overline{x_2}$&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$x_2$}&$\overline{x_2}$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for including a minimal example document with your question.  Is the question how  to add the red annotation to the table?

Comment: Yes I've no idea how add the red annotation

Comment: There are several packages which are dedicated to Karnaugh maps. `karnaugh-map` (with a hyphen) has examples close to what you're asking for.

Comment: see the second @Ignasi answer on question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140567/drawing-karnaughs-maps-in-latex?. your question is actually duplicate to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple version to overlay your map is to use `tikzmark` (although your Karnaugh map does not really look nice). For ease of use I made all columns with bits equally wide (you may want to add some height with `\extrarowheight` or stretch the table using `\arraystretch`).

[image: karnaugh map]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}  
\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{c|wc{1em}|wc{1em}|wc{1em}|wc{1em}|c} 
 $y_0$ & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$x_0$} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\overline{x_0}$}\\ \cline{1-5}
 $x_1$    &1\tikzmark{c1}&0&0&\tikzmark{c2}1&$\overline{x_3}$\\\cline{2-6}
       &0&\tikzmark{ul}1&1&0&$x_3$\\\cline{1-5}
 $\overline{x_1}$   &0&1&1\tikzmark{br}&0&\\\cline{2-6}
       &1\tikzmark{c3}&0&0&\tikzmark{c4}1&$\overline{x_3}$\\\cline{2-5}
       &$\overline{x_2}$&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$x_2$}&$\overline{x_2}$\\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[red,rounded corners=5pt] ([xshift=-1.25em,yshift=-2pt]pic cs:c1) -| ++(1.75em,1.25em);
    \draw[red,rounded corners=5pt] ([xshift=-1.25em,yshift=7pt]pic cs:c3) -| ++(1.75em,-1.25em);
    \draw[red,rounded corners=5pt] ([xshift=1.25em,yshift=-2pt]pic cs:c2) -| ++(-1.75em,1.25em);
    \draw[red,rounded corners=5pt] ([xshift=1.25em,yshift=7pt]pic cs:c4) -| ++(-1.75em,-1.25em);
    \draw[red,rounded corners=5pt] ([xshift=-4pt,yshift=.7em]pic cs:ul) rectangle ([yshift=-.3em,xshift=4pt]pic cs:br);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Btw: The `w` array specifier needs a recent version of `array`.

Comment: Thanks, that's look very good. But after I copy the code in my document and try to compile have the Error "! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (w): `c' used.". I've do idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Svenja As I've written in the comment this specifier needs a very recent version of `array`. You could of course use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1em}` instead (or `c` and adjust the lengths).

Answer (score 6):

This is a completely different approach taken from my answer at [How to draw a 8x8 Karnaugh map in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425128/how-to-draw-a-8x8-karnaugh-map-in-latex). It does also show some different outcome, but as a personal preference I find it more comfortable (at least the drawing part in the document).

[image: karnaugh map]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kvmap}

\begin{document}
    \begin{kvmap}
    \begin{kvmatrix}{x_0,x_2,x_1,x_3}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{kvmatrix}
    \bundle[color=red]{1}{1}{2}{2}
    \draw[kvbundle,red] (00.south west) -| (00.north east);
    \draw[kvbundle,red] (33.south west) |- (33.north east);
    \draw[kvbundle,red] (30.south east) -| (30.north west);
    \draw[kvbundle,red] (03.south east) |- (03.north west);
    \end{kvmap}
\end{document}
```

*Update 2018-09-21:* This answer now uses the `kvmap` package. You may find the old code in the edit history of this answer.

Comment: No, that's look good. My Problem is I do this KV-diagramm for the uni and the task is to do it with the KV-diagramm in my question because of that I don't want use a different diagramm.